# Trouble with input in Python roulette game

Tags: python

How can I prompt the user to input a number between `1` and `36` and how does the program go through the `elif` statement?

```
elif user_bet == (1) (2) :
    print('You are betting on %s \n Good Luck!' %(user_bet))
    money = int(input("What is your bet:"))
    number = random.randint(1,36)
    if number == user_bet:
        user_flow = 36 * money + user_flow
        print("Excellent Job! You now have %d" %(user_flow))
    else:
        user_flow = user_flow - money 
        print('Bad news, you now have %d' %(user_flow))
```

Comment: In your case, it would be if `1 <= user_bet <= 36`

Comment: What is the actual problem?